# Bootstrap Inline Text and Image (Constant Height)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have two columns: One column consists of an image and other consists of texts!

Here's my site built with Bootstrap (I want your help for that PAZO MALL PARTNERS and the IMAGE): http://pazomall.storehippo.com/sellers/5abe45a880c39ba146324194

When you resize the browser, you can see image goes on shrinking i.e. becomes responsive.

What I want is the image to have a constant height(85px) and the text column to vertically center align respective to the image div.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, First set image equal height, then you should refer for display:flex concept. It's easy to help you. Or if you need code level helping please share your code

Comment: @tam Can you help me using Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: Remember that questions should be helpful to future readers. Please post the relevant code in the question instead of linking to external sites that may change over time.

Comment: ZimSystem ya, I agree... @Sanjay Please post the relevant code.